# finding occurrence of a letter in different positions in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am trying to find the occurrence of a letter in the middle position in a word. I was able to figure out for first and last. The middle position is anything other than first and last. Could anyone help me out with this ?

```
words = words.flatMap(lambda line: line.split())
chars = words.map(lambda x: (x,list(x)))
occurrence1 = chars.map(lambda x: (('first',x[1]
    [0]),1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x+y)
occurrence2 = chars.map(lambda x: (('last',x[1]
    [-1]),1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x+y)
occurrence3 = chars.map(lambda x[1:-1]: x.countByKey())

print(occurrence1.collect())
print(occurrence2.collect())
#print(occurrence3.collect())
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop the first and the last element and flatten

```
from operator import add

words.flatMap(lambda xs: ((x, 1) for x in xs[1:-1])).reduceByKey(add)
```

To count by specific position:

```
words.flatMap(
    lambda xs: (((i, x), 1) for (i, x) in enumerate(xs[1:-1]))
).reduceByKey(add)
```